# Convert XML to EXCEL using VSTO in C#

Tags: c#, vsto, export-to-excel

I have an XML file having some data from other interfaces and currently I am using a XSLT to convert it to a EXCEL file. But I would like to do the same using VSTO. If anyone can point me in right direction I will be highly thankful.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally recommend this book:
[http://www.amazon.com/Visual-Studio-Tools-Office-2007/dp/0321533216/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1330967538&sr=1-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321533216)

For getting started, the official Microsoft site resources:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hh128771.aspx